# Prove that there are no theorems in which there are no occurrences of disjunction

Tags: logic

*Ref* : Peter Andrews, *An Introduction to Mathematical Logic and Type Theory To Truth Through Proof* (1986).

**Exercise X1210** :

> Does $\mathscr{P}$ have any theorems in which there are no occurrences of disjunction?

**Claim:**

No such theorems exist.

**Discussion:**

I think I should prove this by assuming that such a theorem exists and then look for a contradiction. However, I am unsure how to proceed. Can someone give me some pointers? I am studying mathematical logic on my own and occasionally have problems with the exercises. I will be grateful for any help.

**Definitions:**

Let $\mathscr{P}$ be the following ligistic system:

> The *set of wffs* of $\mathscr{P}$ is the intersection of all sets $\mathscr{S}$ of formulas such that:
>
> (i) $\mathbf{p} \in \mathscr{S}$ for each propositional variable $\mathbf{p}$.
>
> (ii) For each formula $\mathbf{A}$ if $\mathbf{A} \in \mathscr{S}$, then $\mathord{\sim} \mathbf{A} \in \mathscr{S}$.
>
> (iii) For all formulas $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathscr{B}$, if $\mathbf{A} \in \mathscr{S}$ and $\mathbf{B} \in \mathscr{S}$, then $\left[\mathbf{A} \lor \mathbf{B} \right] \in \mathscr{S}$.

The Axioms of $\mathscr{P}$ are

> (1) $\mathord{\sim} \left[ \mathbf{A} \vee \mathbf{A} \right] \vee \mathbf{A}$
>
> (2) $\mathord{\sim} \mathbf{A} \vee {}_\blacksquare \mathbf{B} \vee \mathbf{A}$
>
> (3) $\mathord{\sim} \left[ \mathord{\sim} \mathbf{A} \vee \mathbf{B} \right] \vee {}_\blacksquare \mathord{\sim} \left[ \mathbf{C} \vee \mathbf{A} \right] \vee {}_\blacksquare \mathbf{B} \vee \mathbf{C}$

$\mathscr{P}$ has one rule of inference:

> **Modus Ponens (MP).** From $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathord{\sim} \mathbf{A} \vee \mathbf{B}$ to infer $\mathbf{B}$.

A *theorem* of $\mathscr{p}$ is defined as follows:

> **Def1.** A *proof of a wff $\mathbf{B}$ from the set $\mathscr{H}$ of hypotheses* is a finite sequence $\mathbf{B}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{B}_m$ of wffs such that $\mathbf{B}_m$ is $\mathbf{B}$ and for each $j$ ($1 \leq j \leq m$) at least one of the following conditions is satisfied:
>
> (1) $\mathbf{B}_j$ is an axiom.
>
> (2) $\mathbf{B}_j$ is an member of $\mathscr{H}$.
>
> (3) $\mathbf{B}_j$ is inferred by modus ponents from wffs $\mathbf{B}_i$ and $\mathbf{B}_k$, where $i < j$ and $k < j$.
>
> **Def2.** A *proof* of a wff $\mathbf{B}$ is a proof of $\mathbf{B}$ from the emtpy set of hypotheses.
>
> **Def3.** A *theorem* is a wff which has a proof.

Comment: Hint: There are very few **formulas** that are disjunction-free.

Comment: @AndréNicolas The wffs which are disjunction-free consist of the propositional variables and formulas of the form $\mathord{\sim} \mathbf{A}$ where $\mathbf{A}$ is also disjunction-free. So I guess I need to prove that neither of these is a theorem.

Comment: That's right, they are all a finite string of $\sim$ followed by a propositional variable. The easiest approach is semantic, if a formula is a theorem then it has truth value T under all truth assignments to its propositional variables.

Comment: @AndréNicolas So I'm probably just making this harder than it is. Such formulas cannot have a value of *truth* under all assignments. Since there is only one propositional variable, there are only two assignments. One of these will result in a value of *truth* and one will result in a value of *falsehood*.

Comment: That's under the assumption that the result "if a formula is a theorem $\dots$" that I mentioned earlier has already been proved. If it hasn't, one has to prove it, a fairly straightforward induction on the length of a proof. But that's a much bigger and more important thing than this exercise.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Right. I am at the point in the text where I have gone through the proof that all theorems are tautologies, so I feel fine using that result as part of my own proof for this exercise.

Comment: OK, settled then.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Fortunately, the books I am studying from already proved 1 and 2.